# Automatically cast value type to column type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

TL;DR; In short, what I need is to somehow cast `text` to `unknown` from where Postgres will magically cast that to correct type; or some alternative solution to this while keeping in mind things that I want to avoid.

Error in question:

```
ERROR: column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type text
```

Say I've got this table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE unknown_test (
  id int,
  some_timestamp timestamp,
  value1 int,
  value2 int,
  value3 text);
```

Currently I'm doing DML on that table with queries like that:

```
INSERT INTO unknown_test (id, some_timestamp, value1, value2, value3)
VALUES ('5', '2018-01-10 14:11:03.763396', '3', '15', 'test2');
```

So values are `unknown` type and Postgres has some kind of built in cast for that (it is not in `select * from pg_cast where castsource = 'unknown'::regtype;`). This works, but is somewhat slow.

What I want to do is this (obviously I have actual table, not `values()`):

```
INSERT INTO unknown_test (id, some_timestamp, value1, value2, value3)
SELECT json_data->>'id', json_data->>'some_timestamp', json_data->>'value1', json_data->>'value2', json_data->>'value3'
  FROM (VALUES (jsonb_build_object('id', 1, 'some_timestamp', now(), 'value1', 21, 'value2', 5, 'value3', 'test')),
               (jsonb_build_object('id', 2, 'some_timestamp', now(), 'value1', 22, 'value2', 15, 'value3', 'test2')),
               (jsonb_build_object('id', 3, 'some_timestamp', now(), 'value1', 32, 'value2', 25, 'value3', 'test5')),
               (jsonb_build_object('id', 4, 'some_timestamp', now(), 'value1', 42, 'value2', 55, 'value3', 'test7'))
       ) AS j(json_data);
```

Sadly, those will give `text` type and will complain that I need to explicitly cast it. I can't do that, because I don't know what types those are. I could find out of course by checking `pg_catalog` or by storing in json data info about type. Both of those require some additional computation and/or storage and I want to avoid any unnecessary overhead to this (my pg_catalog is really fat).

Second thing I want to avoid is `CREATE CAST` for text type, unless someone can assure me it won't break anything.

Doing loop and dynamic SQL to get `unknown` type is my current approach and I need something faster, so my idea was not to use loop, but table instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_populate_record` for this:

```
SELECT (jsonb_populate_record(null::unknown_test, json_data)).*
FROM ...
```

This will create a record of the same type as the table `unknown_test` and then the whole record is expanded into individual columns using the `(...).*` syntax.

This requires that the (first level) keys in the JSON document have *exactly* the same names as the columns in the table.